# getRequestProperty("Authorization") always returns null

Tags: java, http, authorization, oauth, httpurlconnection

I am trying to read the authorization header for an HTTP request (because I need to add something to it), but I always get null for the header value. Other headers work fine.

```
public void testAuth() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    URLConnection request = new URL("http://google.com").openConnection();
    request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "MyHeader");
    request.setRequestProperty("Stackoverflow", "anotherHeader");
    // works fine
    assertEquals("anotherHeader", request.getRequestProperty("Stackoverflow"));
    // Auth header returns null
    assertEquals("MyHeader", request.getRequestProperty("Authorization"));
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a "security" feature? Is there a way to make this work with URLConnection, or do I need to use another HTTP client library?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apparently, it's a security "feature". The URLConnection is actually an instance of [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java.html). It defines `getRequestProperty` as:

```
    public String getRequestProperty (String key) {
        // don't return headers containing security sensitive information
        if (key != null) {
            for (int i=0; i < EXCLUDE_HEADERS.length; i++) {
                if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(EXCLUDE_HEADERS[i])) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return requests.findValue(key);
    }
```

The `EXCLUDE_HEADERS` array is defined as:

```
   // the following http request headers should NOT have their values
   // returned for security reasons.
   private static final String[] EXCLUDE_HEADERS = {
           "Proxy-Authorization",
           "Authorization"
   };
```

Comment: That would explain it. And also why the same code works fine on Google App Engine (where they use their own implementation of HttpUrlConnection).

Answer (score 0):

I am not happy about the extra dependencies, but following the [suggestion to switch to Commons Http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851953/httpurlconnection-vs-apache-commons-http) solved the immediate problem for me.

I'd still like to know what the problem was with my original code.

Answer (score 0):

As [Devon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864062/getrequestpropertyauthorization-always-returns-null#answer-2865535) correctly states: it's not a bug, it's a "security" feature

But you don't have to switch to a different library: it is always possible to access the underlying `MessageHeader`-collection via reflection and extract the "Authorization"-header value.

After some headscratch i've managed to come up with a working [snippet here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559791/access-private-messageheader-field-requests-from-httpurlconnection-via-reflect/69562580#69562580).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `URLConnection.addRequestProperty()`?
This is how I use to add HTTP Request Headers.

Comment: same result: the other header works, Authorization stays null

Comment: Have you tried something like 

`request.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + hashed("username:password"));` where `hashed` is Base64 hash of the string?

See if your `assertEquals` return the result.

Comment: Even so, I used OAuth Authentication using URLConnection and it works for me. If that doesn't work, use HTTP Client from Apache (Strongly recommended).

Comment: This should've been a comment on the post.