# how to get "Authentication" header from doGet request if I don't want to switch to other libraries?

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, request

I just realized that my base64 encoded Header "Authentication" can't be read 
with request.getHeader("Authentication").

I found this post about that it's a security Feature in URLConnection

[getRequestProperty("Authorization") always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864062/getrequestpropertyauthorization-always-returns-null)
, i don't know why but it seems to be true for request.getHeader as well.

How can i still get this Header if l don't want to Switch to other libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching through https://fossies.org/dox/apache-tomcat-6.0.45-src/catalina_2connector_2Request_8java_source.html#l01947 and found a section where restricted headers will be used if Globals.IS_SECURITY_ENABLED is set.

Since I'm working on a reverse Proxy and only Need to pass requests/Responses through I did simply set "System.setSecurityManager(null);" and for my case it might be a valid solution but if you want to use authentication there is no reason to use this Workaround.

My bad, it does work with https now.

Comment: Won't work in unit tests unfortunately – tried setting `System.setSecurityManager(null);` and `connection.getRequestProperty("Authorization")` still returns null although explicitely set before. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution did not work for me – may have something to do with different runtime environments.

However, i've managed to come up with a [working snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559791/access-private-messageheader-field-requests-from-httpurlconnection-via-reflect/69562580#69562580) to access the underlying `MessageHeader`-collection via reflection and extract the "Authorization"-header value.