# Access private MessageHeader field ("Authorization") of HttpURLConnection via Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, httpurlconnection

Currently writing unit tests for an existing library, i am trying to work around the limitation (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864062/getrequestpropertyauthorization-always-returns-null)) that you cannot retrieve an already set "Authorization"-header, using reflection.

The code i'm using is a very typical snippet that i've used dozens of times to access private fields:

```java
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://stackoverflow.com").openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic Zm9vYmFyOnNlY3JldA==");
try {
    Field requests = conn.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("requests");
    requests.setAccessible(true);
    MessageHeader headers = (MessageHeader) requests.get(conn); // Problem: returns null
    return headers.getValue(headers.getKey("Authorization"));
} catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However – extraction via `Field::get` fails and `null` is returned (see commented line).

Looking at the base class of `HttpUrlConnection`, which is `URLConnection` i know i'm looking for the `requests` field. Debugging through it, i can see the field i want to extract (even showing the "Authorization" values):

[image: Debug watch]

In the line of code that fails to return the `MessageHeader` object, it looks like i have a reference to the field in `URLConnection`:

[image: Debug watch]

But i must be missing something here – can anybody tell, what?

##### Update

What confuses me is

1. the fact that i'm only importing `URLConnection` and `HttpURLConnection` from the `java.net`-package. However from looking at the first debug screenshot, the `conn`-object implementation is clearly coming from `sun.net.www.protocol.https`.
2. the `DelegateHttpsURLConnection` member (also shown in the first debug screenshot)

Comment: If you’re using Java 11 or later, it’s probably safer to use the new [java.net.http package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) rather than relying on reflection.

Comment: @VGR Stuck with java 8 here. If i wouldn't need to cover the existing code base with tests first before any refactoring can take place, i would have switched to Commons Http already.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `getClass()` on an object, you get its actual runtime type which doesn’t have to match the compile-time type, as it may be a subclass of it. Therefore, traversing the class hierarchy via `getSuperclass()` is fragile.

When you know the class declaring the field beforehand, you can just use that class, e.g.

```java
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
    new URL("https://stackoverflow.com").openConnection();
try {
  Field f = URLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("requests");
  f.setAccessible(true);
  System.out.println(f.get(conn));
}
catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This, however, will always print `null`, as this specific connection implementation doesn’t use its superclass state, but delegates to a different implementation. As you’ve found out yourself, it’s stored in a field called `delegate`.

```java
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
    new URL("https://stackoverflow.com").openConnection();
for(Class<?> c = conn.getClass(); c != URLConnection.class; c = c.getSuperclass())
  System.out.print(c.getName() + " > ");
System.out.println(URLConnection.class.getName());

Field delegate = conn.getClass().getDeclaredField("delegate");
delegate.setAccessible(true);
conn = (HttpURLConnection)delegate.get(conn);

for(Class<?> c = conn.getClass(); c != URLConnection.class; c = c.getSuperclass())
  System.out.print(c.getName() + " > ");
System.out.println(URLConnection.class.getName());

Field requests = URLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("requests");
requests.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println(requests.get(conn));
```

This prints

```
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl > javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection > java.net.HttpURLConnection > java.net.URLConnection
sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection > sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection > sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection > java.net.HttpURLConnection > java.net.URLConnection
null
```

Showing that these two objects have a different class hierarchy and thus, traversing it assuming a particular depth is indeed fragile.

It also prints again `null`, because even this implementation class doesn’t use the `requests` field inherited from `URLConnection`. Instead, the class `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` declares its own field, with the same name, which contains the actual `MessageHeader` object. That’s why performing `getSuperclass().getSuperclass()` on the implementation class of the delegate leads to the correct field, which is not `URLConnection`’s.

When we know this beforehand, we can use

```java
HttpURLConnection conn =
    (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://stackoverflow.com").openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic Zm9vYmFyOnNlY3JldA==");

Field delegate = Class.forName("sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl")
    .getDeclaredField("delegate");
Field requests = Class.forName("sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection")
    .getDeclaredField("requests");
AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new Field[] { delegate, requests}, true);
sun.net.www.MessageHeader headers =
    (sun.net.www.MessageHeader)requests.get(delegate.get(conn));
return headers.findValue("Authorization");
```

Since you’re accessing the `sun.net. …` package(s) anyway, you could refer to these classes directly instead of using `Class.forName`, but I considered the latter more robust in this specific case, as all these classes have easy to confuse names and even sometimes the same simple name, just differing by their package.

```java
private String getAuthorizationHeaderValue(HttpURLConnection conn) {
  try {
    Field delegate = sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.class.getDeclaredField("delegate");
    Field requests = sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("requests");
    AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new Field[] { delegate, requests}, true);
    sun.net.www.MessageHeader headers = (sun.net.www.MessageHeader)requests.get(delegate.get(conn));
    return headers.findValue("Authorization");
  } catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stepping down the delegate-ladder one step further works and successfully manages to extract the "Authorization"-header value:

```java
private String getAuthorizationHeaderValue(HttpURLConnection conn) {

    try {
        Field delegateField = conn.getClass().getDeclaredField("delegate");
        delegateField.setAccessible(true);
        DelegateHttpsURLConnection delegate = (DelegateHttpsURLConnection) delegateField.get(conn);
        Field requests = delegate.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("requests");
        requests.setAccessible(true);
        MessageHeader headers = (MessageHeader) requests.get(delegate);
        return headers.getValue(headers.getKey("Authorization"));
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Looks awful and feels quirky to me – as you can tell from my initial question i'm still confused about the class hierarchy of those objects. So if anybody can shed some light on the confusion and come up with a shorter solution, i'm still open to accept that as the better answer.