# HttpsURLConnection strange behaviour on android2.2

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, http-status-codes, httpurlconnection, httpconnection

I am trying to open a https connection in android. When i run the code below in android 3 or 1.6 everything works like a charm. But in android 2.2 sometimes it gives me -1 connection response. 
Android 2.2 : 
connection attemp gives -1 response code 
sleep 200 miliseconds 
connection attemp gives -1 response code 
sleep 200 miliseconds  
connection attemp gives http200 

Another trial 
connection attemp gives -1 response code 
sleep 200 miliseconds 
connection attemp gives http200 
**My question is how can i overcome this chaning response in android 2.2. I dont even know where to look. I will appriciate if someone can guide me in the right direction.**


Here is the code:

```
HttpsURLConnection con;
    URL adress = new URL("https:\\www.url.com/service.asp?someparam");
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
        }
    } };
    try {
        SSLContext sc = null;
        try {
            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        }
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) adress.openConnection();
    ((HttpsURLConnection) con).setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    Log.d("response code", "" + con.getResponseCode());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to disable keep alive and if this doesn't help, try to disable caching:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
con = (HttpsURLConnection) adress.openConnection();
con.setUseCaches(false);
```

More information [is in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440957/httpurlconnection-getresponsecode-returns-1-on-second-invocation).

Answer (score 2):

HttpURLConnection has some bugs before 2.3

It is recommended to use Apache HttpClient for 2.2 and earlier. and HttlURLConnection for 2.3 and onwards.

see this [Developer Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for more information on it.