# Using Android Volley for a JsonRequest throws Could not retrieve response code from HttpUrlConnection every 2 requests

Tags: android, android-volley, httpurlconnection

I've been using Volley for a while but today I'm facing a very weird problem.
I'm making a Post JsonRequest successfully, but if I try again the request to the same service it fails, if I try once again it's successful and so on.

If the request is successful and I restart the app, the next request will still be successful, then it fails, it succeed and so on.

The same happens with a StringRequest.

What happens is that in HurlStack class I fall in this if:

```
if (responseCode == -1) {            
// -1 is returned by getResponseCode() if the response code could not be retrieved.            
// Signal to the caller that something was wrong with the connection.

 throw new IOException("Could not retrieve response code from HttpUrlConnection.");

 }
```

but I know that even in this case the request was correctly posted to the server (I checked the logs).

Comment: I'm also running into this problem.  I'd love to know if you found what the issue was.

Comment: I also have this issue, but only if I pass in a `HurlStack` to `Volley#newRequestQueue()`.  If I pass just the `Context`, I have no issue.

Comment: The solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440957/httpurlconnection-getresponsecode-returns-1-on-second-invocation) solved my problem.