# java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I need get a response code, but it's throw a  IOException. I don't know what's the matter!

```
    try
    {
        url = new URL(urlBuilder.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod(METHOD_GET);
        conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "*/*");
        conn.connect();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();   //throw IOException:Received authentication challenge is null
        if (responseCode == HTTP_OK)
        {
            inStream = conn.getInputStream();
            response = getResponse(inStream);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "response code："+responseCode;
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    return response;
}
```

the IOException is :

```
05-03 20:14:01.577: WARN/System.err(1515): java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1694)
05-03 20:14:01.577: INFO/QQWeiBo(1515): Received authentication challenge is null
05-03 20:14:01.577: WARN/System.err(1515): java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
05-03 20:14:01.577: WARN/System.err(1515): java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1694)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.service.SyncHttp.httpGet(SyncHttp.java:72)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.service.Weibo.getRequestToken(Weibo.java:45)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity.startWebView(MainActivity.java:95)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity.authorization(MainActivity.java:83)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1694)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.service.SyncHttp.httpGet(SyncHttp.java:72)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.service.Weibo.getRequestToken(Weibo.java:45)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity.startWebView(MainActivity.java:95)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity.authorization(MainActivity.java:83)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.service.SyncHttp.httpGet(SyncHttp.java:72)
05-03 20:14:01.596: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.service.Weibo.getRequestToken(Weibo.java:45)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity.startWebView(MainActivity.java:95)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity.authorization(MainActivity.java:83)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.szy.weibo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-03 20:14:01.616: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-03 20:14:01.616: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 20:14:01.606: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-03 20:14:01.616: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 20:14:01.627: WARN/System.err(1515):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 20:14:01.647: WARN/System.err(1515):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please see my response and +1/accept if you like it!

Answer (score 6):

Most often, you can get a response code by calling .getResponseCode() on your connection a second time. This was confusing for me at first, but if you read HttpURLConnectionImpl enough times your eyes will stop bleeding and see the truth...

If you modify your code in this way, you will get the response code:

```
try
    {
        url = new URL(urlBuilder.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod(METHOD_GET);
        conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "*/*");
        conn.connect();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();   //throw IOException:Received authentication challenge is null
        if (responseCode == HTTP_OK)
        {
            inStream = conn.getInputStream();
            response = getResponse(inStream);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "response code："+responseCode;
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Here you can get the correct response code
        if (conn != null) {
            int responseCodeAfterException = conn.getResponseCode();
            // Handle according to new response code
        }
        // Maybe don't throw e if 401?
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    return response;
}
```

See responseCodeAfterException.

Answer (score 3):

If you can make changes to server side you could make sure you have correct headers sent with 401 status code. From http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2

> 10.4.2 401 Unauthorized
>
> The request requires user authentication. **The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field** (section 14.47) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If
>   the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401
>   response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
>   credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the
>   prior response, and the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the
>   entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include
>   relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is
>   explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access
>   Authentication" [43].

I was using same code as @tj-thind until I ran into situation described by @Chiara. Then I added `WWW-Authenticate` and `Content-Length` headers to my server script and now I can get correct 401 status code without IOException when using `getResponseCode()`.

See also [IOException: "Received authentication challenge is null" (Apache Harmony/Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357372/ioexception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null-apache-harmony-android)

Comment: Judging by the logs this is a Weibo problem (one I'm having too) so changing the server side isn't an option, but this is really useful to know, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue myself before. That exception is actually being thrown by `getResponseCode` in the event of a 401, which is the HTTP code for Unauthorized. This seems to be unique to the Android implementation of `HttpURLConnection`. The easiest way to deal with it, I find, is just to deal with 401's in the catch block.

```java
catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    //Probably got a 401 here
    response = "response code："+401;
}
```

Comment: If there's an issue with this answer at least leave a comment.

Comment: That's to much general and you could be masking some IOException that have nothing to do with the 401 error. I use your approach, but, I add an extra check on that:  catch(IOException e){
   if(e.getMessage().contains("authentication challenge")){
    return HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
   }
   else{
    throw e;
   }
  }

Comment: @Chiara: You did a good job! The error-message changed in Android 4.0.4 and 4.1.0 ... both are caught by your test. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810447/httpurlconnection-worked-fine-in-android-2-x-but-not-in-4-1-no-authentication-c