# android - no authentication challenges found Error with Get request

Tags: android, restful-authentication, auth0

Its first time I am using [auth0](https://auth0.com/) to generate **token** to secure connection with my web service.

I used it for logging - I pass email & password this my url and I get token

this my code , and its work fine

```
 public String post_to_webservice() {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        final String[] line = {null};
        final BufferedReader[] reader = {null};


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "test"));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "test"));
                    URL url = new URL("https://validate.co.nz/api/public/api/authenticate");
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setReadTimeout(30000);

                    OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(getQuery(params));
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    connection.connect();
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        reader[0] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                        while ((line[0] = reader[0].readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuilder.append(line[0]);
                        }
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    if (reader[0] != null) {
                        try {
                            reader[0].close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String message = stringBuilder.toString();
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);
                            Token = (String) object.get("token");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "token is : " + Token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }
                });

            }

        }).start();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }


private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

but I need use the same url but with get request to get data by passing my token 
in header

here is my try

```
 public String get_request() {

        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        final String[] line = {null};
        final BufferedReader[] reader = {null};
        final String[] result = {null};

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
// second try pass token here
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", Token));


                    URL url = new URL("https://validate.co.nz/api/public/api/authenticate");
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// I try put my token in header but its fail 
                    String base64Auth = Base64.encodeToString(Token.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // get request
                    connection.setReadTimeout(300000);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);

                    OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(getQuery(params));
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    connection.connect();
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        reader[0] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                        while ((line[0] = reader[0].readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuilder.append(line[0]);
                        }
                        result[0] =stringBuilder.toString();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    result[0] = e.getMessage();

                } finally {
                    if (reader[0] != null) {
                        try {
                            reader[0].close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result: " + result[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });

            }

        }).start();
        return result[0];

    }
```

I get this error **no authentication challenges found** 
any suggestion thank you

Comment: What is your web service? Is it Asp.Net Web API?

Comment: I am using PHP Laravel

Comment: Sorry, i am not familiar with it.

Comment: thank you , I try this answer but its dosent work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810447/httpurlconnection-worked-fine-in-android-2-x-but-not-in-4-1-no-authentication-c

Comment: You should your token value for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem perhaps is `setDoOutput()`, I have tested this sample code, you can read my comments

```
private class APIRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {            
            String token = "0123456789";            
            URL url = new URL("https://validate.co.nz/api/public/api/authenticate");                
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);         
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); //HERE: if TRUE, receive "No authentication challenges found"; if FALSE, receive "token_not_provided"              
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // I think if GET, should setDoOutput(false);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream;
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            } else {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            }                
            return String.valueOf(urlConnection.getResponseCode()) + " " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);            
    }
}
```

Comment: just change Basic to Bearer

Comment: Glad to hear that you fix this problem!

Comment: Thank you you save my day , I work in this issue from 2 days

Answer (score 1):

I am developing an Android app that uses OAuth authentication to authenticate requests to a RESTful web service. I do not know anything about the specific OAuth package you are using and cannot be certain about the cause of the problem you are having. But, based on differences between what you are doing and what I am doing, I see two potential problems:

1. You may not be using the right token in the HTTP header. In particular, the token you are using may be a refresh token rather than an access token, and you may need to use the access token instead.
2. You may be inserting the token in the header incorrectly. In my case, I insert the token using:

   `connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);`