# HttpUrlConnection doesn't work in Jelly Bean

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm having an issue concerning HttpUrlConnection. It works perfectly in every OS besides JellyBean and I have no idea why. I have 2 emulators next to each other, one running Nougat, another running JellyBean API 18, in the Nougat the request goes through and in the JellyBean it doesn't

Here is my code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(60000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream(); <-- Gets stuck here and times out after the 60 seconds I gave in the readtimeout
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(paramList));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int result2 = bis.read();
while(result2 != -1) {
    buf.write((byte) result2);
    result2 = bis.read();
}
result = buf.toString();
```

The error thrown is UnknownHostException: No address associated with hostname but I figure it is not relevant as it comes from the time out expiration.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try see: [Topic in Stakeoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810447/httpurlconnection-worked-fine-in-android-2-x-but-not-in-4-1-no-authentication-c, "Stakeoverflow") 

- my advice is: use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html, "Android Developer")

Comment: i tried your snipped and it worked. I `POST`ed `hello world` to `http://stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: and `UnknownHostException: No address associated with hostname` happens, among other reasons, when there is no internet connection

Comment: Check my post, I clearly said I have two emulators next to each other and it works with API 25 and not API 18 (4.3)

Comment: It get's stuck at conn.getOutPutStream();

Comment: Dont use an emulator. Take a real device.

Comment: `The error thrown is UnknownHostException:`. Then show the url you use. What kind of host?

Comment: `writer.close();
os.close();`. Do not close the streams as it will close the connection too.

Comment: `conn.connect();`. It makes no sense trying to connect if you already have a connection and already send your data. So remove.

Comment: `i tried your snipped and it worked. I POSTed hello world to http://stackoverflow.com/ `. Interesting. What data did you get as response? @nandsito

Comment: i got stackoverflow home HTML

Comment: @greenapps it is a link which you can only access from my working web connection, so no point posting it here. I know the code works, at least for all the Android versions except jelly bean. Have you tried running that code from a jelly bean phone/emulator? It seems it doesn't work with any of them. I don't have a single record from request with jelly bean phones

Comment: ???? Have you removed the code lines which i asked you to remove? Why dont you react?

Comment: I got that bit of code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post which always worked. Seems to be pretty much the same everywhere. I did remove the lines you said and got the same result. In debug mode, the code never goes past `conn.getOutputStream()`

Comment: in the JellyBean emulator, open a web-browser (ex, the one that comes with the OS), and try to access your link, what is the result ?

Comment: Interesting. My emulator running Jelly bean cannot reach the link through the browser

Comment: ahaa, so it's not about the code :), it's network issue, NAT and so on, now you know where to look ;)

Comment: I was able to replicate my error and it had to do with the SSLv3 protocol from versions below 4.4. Thank you everyone for trying to help me out