# java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null in ICS 4.0.3

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to logoff from the server. But it returns "0" response code with this exception. I'm using GET verb to do this.

**LogCat**

```
10-17 14:54:13.261: W/System.err(868): java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
10-17 14:54:13.284: W/System.err(868):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:397)
10-17 14:54:13.284: W/System.err(868):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
10-17 14:54:13.304: W/System.err(868):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:276)
10-17 14:54:13.324: W/System.err(868):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:479)
10-17 14:54:13.324: W/System.err(868):  at com.remote.synchronizer.haris.CustomHttpClient.executeGet(CustomHttpClient.java:131)
10-17 14:54:13.354: W/System.err(868):  at com.remote.synchronizer.haris.OptionsActivity$1$3$1.run(OptionsActivity.java:87)
10-17 14:54:13.364: W/System.err(868):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-17 14:54:13.384: W/System.err(868):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-17 14:54:13.384: W/System.err(868):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 14:54:13.404: W/System.err(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-17 14:54:13.424: W/System.err(868):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 14:54:13.424: W/System.err(868):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 14:54:13.454: W/System.err(868):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-17 14:54:13.474: W/System.err(868):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-17 14:54:13.474: W/System.err(868):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 14:54:13.484: E/HTTP Response(868): java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
```

**CustomHttpClient.java**

```
public class CustomHttpClient {

    static HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    static HttpURLConnection connection = null; 

    public static int executePost(String url, String postParameters)
    {
        int response=0;

        OutputStream output = null;
        try
        {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

            connection.connect();

            output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(postParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            response=connection.getResponseCode();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("HTTP Response", e.toString());
        }
        finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                //  connection.disconnect(); 
                if (output != null) 
                    try { output.close(); } 
                catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    public static int executeGet(String url)
    {
        int response=0;

        //HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            //connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            response=connection.getResponseCode();
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("HTTP Response", e.toString());
        }
        finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                //  connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

Before this I'm using DefaultHTTPClient in Gingerbird 2.3 its working perfectly but in ICS DefaultHTTPClient is not working so I need to use HttpURLConnection. POST verb is working fine.

Comment: Please see my response and +1/accept if you like it!

Comment: you have probably seen this, but it is worth a shot sharing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810447/httpurlconnection-worked-fine-in-android-2-x-but-not-in-4-1-no-authentication-c

Answer (score 9):

You can get the response code after an exception if you call .getResponseCode() a second time on the connection object. This is because the first time you call .getResponseCode() an internal state is set that enables .getResponseCode() to return without throwing an exception.

Example:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = ...;
try {
    // Will throw IOException if server responds with 401.
    connection.getResponseCode(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Will return 401, because now connection has the correct internal state.
    int responsecode = connection.getResponseCode(); 
}
```

I have also answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15972969/816017

Answer (score 3):

`HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` throws `java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null` when it encounters malformed HTTP 401 header. Do you receive `WWW-Authenticate` and `Content-Length` headers from server in addition to `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` header? See [IOException: "Received authentication challenge is null" (Apache Harmony/Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357372/ioexception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null-apache-harmony-android)

If you can't make changes to server, then you can catch that exception (thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904318/262462)

```
try {
    response=connection.getResponseCode();
}
catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    if (e.getMessage().contains("authentication challenge")) {
        response = HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
    } else { throw e; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens beause the server sends a 401 (Unauthorized) but does not give a "WWW-Authenticate" which is a hint for the client what to do next. The "WWW-Authenticate" Header tells the client which kind of authentication is needed (either [Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or [Digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)). This is usually not very useful in headless HTTP clients, but that's how the standard is defined. The error occurs because the lib tries to parse the "WWW-Authenticate" header but can't.

Possible solutions if you can change the server:

- Add a fake "WWW-Authenticate" header like: `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="fake"`. This is a mere workaround not a solution, but it should work and the HTTP client is satisfied.
- Use HTTP status code `403` instead of `401`. Its semantic is not the same and usually when working with login 401 is a correct response ([see here for detailed discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)) but its close enough.

Possible solutions if you can't change the server:

As @ErikZ wrote in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931791/java-io-ioexception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null-in-ics-4-0-3) you could use a try&catch

```java
HttpURLConnection connection = ...;
try {
    // Will throw IOException if server responds with 401.
    connection.getResponseCode(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Will return 401, because now connection has the correct internal state.
    int responsecode = connection.getResponseCode(); 
}
```

I also posted this here: [java.io.IOException : No authentication challenges found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121213/java-io-ioexception-no-authentication-challenges-found/21534175#21534175)