# Http Status Code in Android Volley when error.networkResponse is null

Tags: android, http-status-codes, android-volley

I am using Google Volley on the Android platform.
I am having a problem in which the `error` parameter in `onErrorResponse` is returning a null `networkResponse`
For the RESTful API I am using, I need to determine the Http Status Code which is often arriving as 401 (SC_UNAUTHORIZED) or 500 (SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR), and I can occasionally check via:

```
final int httpStatusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
if(networkResponse == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
    // Http status code 401: Unauthorized.
}
```

This throws a `NullPointerException` because `networkResponse` is null.

How can I determine the Http Status Code in the function `onErrorResponse`?

Or, how can I ensure `error.networkResponse` is non-null in `onErrorResponse`?

Comment: In Kotlin, `VolleyError.networkResponse` is not nullable, yet is still null - super frustrating

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### 401 Not Supported by Volley

It turns out that it is impossible to guarantee that error.networkResponse is non-null without modifying Google Volley code because of a bug in Volley that throws the Exception `NoConnectionError` for Http Status Code 401 (`HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED`) in BasicNetwork.java (134) prior to setting the value of `networkResponse`.

### Work-Around

Instead of fixing the Volley code, our solution in this case was to modify the Web Service API to send Http Error Code 403 (`HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN`) for the particular case in question.

For this Http Status Code, the value of `error.networkResponse` is non-null in the Volley error handler: `public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)`. And, `error.networkResponse.httpStatusCode` correctly returns `HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN`.

### Other-Suggestions

Rperryng's suggestion of extending the `Request<T>` class may have provided a solution, and is a creative and excellent idea. Thank you very much for the detailed example. I found the optimal solution for our case is to use the work-around because we are fortunate enough to have control of the web services API.

I might opt for fixing the Volley code in one location within BasicNetwork.java if I did not have access to making a simple change at the server.

Answer (score 84):

> Or, how can I ensure error.networkResponse is non-null in
>   onErrorResponse?

My first thought would be to check if the object is null.

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
    if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
        // HTTP Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also try grabbing the Status Code by extending the `Request` class and overriding `parseNetworkResponse`.

For example, if extending the abstract `Request<T>` class

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

    ...
    private int mStatusCode;

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return mStatusCode;
    }
    ...

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        mStatusCode = response.statusCode;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "[raw json]: " + (new String(response.data)));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, mClazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Or, if you are using one of the toolbox classes that already extend the abstract `Request<T>` class and you don't want to muddle up the implementation for `parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse networkResponse)`, continue overriding the method but return the super's implementation via `super.parseNetworkResponse(networkResponse)`

e.g. `StringResponse`

```
public class MyStringRequest extends StringRequest {

    private int mStatusCode;

    public MyStringRequest(int method, String url, Listener<String> listener,
            ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return mStatusCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mStatusCode = response.statusCode;
        return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public class myClazz extends FragmentActivity {


    private Request mMyRequest;
    ...

    public void makeNetworkCall() {
    mMyRequest = new MyNetworkRequest(
            Method.GET, 
            BASE_URL + Endpoint.USER,
            new Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Success

                }
            }, 
            new ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (mMyRequest.getStatusCode() == 401) {
                        // HTTP Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
                    }
                }
            });

    MyVolley.getRequestQueue().add(request);
}
```

Of course, the option to override the method inline is available too

```
public class MyClazz extends FragmentActivity {

    private int mStatusCode;

    ...

    public void makeNetworkCall() {

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
                Method.GET, 
                BASE_URL + Endpoint.USER,
                new Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Success

                    }
                }, 
                new ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (mStatusCode == 401) {
                            // HTTP Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
                        }
                    }
                }) {

                    @Override
                    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        mStatusCode = response.statusCode;
                        return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                    }
                };
    MyVolley.getRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

**Update:**
`HttpStatus` is Deprecated. Use `HttpURLConnection` instead. See [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29941462/421467).

Comment: When server send statusCode 403, parseNetworkResponse method never called.

Comment: If you try to access anything from the inner classes, you are asked to make that variable final.  Not great IMHO

Answer (score 5):

Volley supports HTTP 401 Unauthorized response. But this response MUST include "WWW-Authenticate" header field.

Without this header, 401 response causes `"com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found"` error.

For more detail : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25556453/860189

If you consume 3rd party API's and have no right to change response header, you may consider to implement your own HttpStack because of this exception thrown from HurlStack. Or better, use OkHttpStack as a HttpStack.

Answer (score 4):

You may modify the volley library's performRequest me(toolbox/BasicNetwork.java) method to capture 401 Unauthorized response. (This modified code will also solve http-> https redirect problem of volley)

```
 @Override
public NetworkResponse performRequest(Request<?> request) throws VolleyError {
    long requestStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    while (true) {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        byte[] responseContents = null;
        Map<String, String> responseHeaders = Collections.emptyMap();
        try {
            // Gather headers.
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            addCacheHeaders(headers, request.getCacheEntry());
            httpResponse = mHttpStack.performRequest(request, headers);
            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

            responseHeaders = convertHeaders(httpResponse.getAllHeaders());
            // Handle cache validation.
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED) {

                Entry entry = request.getCacheEntry();
                if (entry == null) {
                    return new NetworkResponse(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED, null,
                            responseHeaders, true,
                            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
                }

                // A HTTP 304 response does not have all header fields. We
                // have to use the header fields from the cache entry plus
                // the new ones from the response.
                // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5
                entry.responseHeaders.putAll(responseHeaders);
                return new NetworkResponse(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED, entry.data,
                        entry.responseHeaders, true,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
            }

            // Handle moved resources
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY || statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
                String newUrl = responseHeaders.get("Location");
                request.setUrl(newUrl);
            }



            // Some responses such as 204s do not have content.  We must check.
            if (httpResponse.getEntity() != null) {
                responseContents = entityToBytes(httpResponse.getEntity());
            } else {
                // Add 0 byte response as a way of honestly representing a
                // no-content request.
                responseContents = new byte[0];
            }

            // if the request is slow, log it.
            long requestLifetime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart;
            logSlowRequests(requestLifetime, request, responseContents, statusLine);

            if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 299) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
            return new NetworkResponse(statusCode, responseContents, responseHeaders, false,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            attemptRetryOnException("socket", request, new TimeoutError());
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            attemptRetryOnException("connection", request, new TimeoutError());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bad URL " + request.getUrl(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            int statusCode = 0;
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = null;
            if (httpResponse != null) {
                statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            } else {
                throw new NoConnectionError(e);
            }
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY ||
                    statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
                VolleyLog.e("Request at %s has been redirected to %s", request.getUrl(), request.getUrl());
            } else {
                VolleyLog.e("Unexpected response code %d for %s", statusCode, request.getUrl());
                if (statusCode==HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN) {
                    throw new VolleyError("403");
                }else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    attemptRetryOnException("auth",
                            request, new AuthFailureError(""));
                }
            }
            if (responseContents != null) {
                networkResponse = new NetworkResponse(statusCode, responseContents,
                        responseHeaders, false, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
                if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    attemptRetryOnException("auth",
                            request, new AuthFailureError(networkResponse));
                } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY ||
                        statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
                    attemptRetryOnException("redirect",
                            request, new AuthFailureError(networkResponse));
                } else {
                    // TODO: Only throw ServerError for 5xx status codes.
                    throw new ServerError(networkResponse);
                }
            } else {
                throw new NetworkError(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in volley error handler use this code

```
@Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                //handler error 401 unauthorized from here
            }
        }
    })
```

Happy coding :D

Answer (score 3):

The `error.networkResponse` will be `null`, if the device has no network connection (you can proof this by enabling the airplane mode). Look at the corresponding [code fragment](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#L154-L159) from the Volley library.

You have to check then, if the error is an instance of the `NoConnectionError`, before you look for the `networkResponse`. I cannot agree, that 401 error is not supported by Volley, I tested it and got a non-null `networkResponse` object back with 401 status code. Look at the corresponding code [here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#L166-L183).

Answer (score 3):

Network response can be received in the following format

```
NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                if(response != null && response.data != null){
                    switch(response.statusCode){
                        case 403:
                            json = new String(response.data);
                            json = trimMessage(json, "error");
                            if(json != null) displayMessage(json);
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I check and grep error.

```
                // TimeoutError => most likely server is down or network is down.
                Log.e(TAG, "TimeoutError: " + (e instanceof TimeoutError));

                Log.e(TAG, "NoConnectionError: " + (e instanceof NoConnectionError));
                /*if(error.getCause() instanceof UnknownHostException ||
                    error.getCause() instanceof EOFException ) {
                    errorMsg = resources.getString(R.string.net_error_connect_network);
                } else {
                    if(error.getCause().toString().contains("Network is unreachable")) {
                        errorMsg = resources.getString(R.string.net_error_no_network);
                    } else {
                        errorMsg = resources.getString(R.string.net_error_connect_network);
                    }
                }*/

                Log.e(TAG, "NetworkError: " + (e instanceof NetworkError));
                Log.e(TAG, "AuthFailureError: " + (e instanceof AuthFailureError));
                Log.e(TAG, "ServerError: " + (e instanceof ServerError));
                //error.networkResponse.statusCode

                // inform dev
                Log.e(TAG, "ParseError: " + (e instanceof ParseError));
                //error.getCause() instanceof JsonSyntaxException

                Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException: " + (e.getCause() instanceof NullPointerException));


                if (e.networkResponse != null) {
                    // 401 => login again
                    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e.networkResponse.statusCode));

                    if (e.networkResponse.data != null) {
                        // most likely JSONString
                        Log.e(TAG, new String(e.networkResponse.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                new String(e.networkResponse.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else if (e.getMessage() == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "e.getMessage");
                    Log.e(TAG, "" + e.getMessage());

                    if (e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage() != "")
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "could not reach server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (e.getCause() != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "e.getCause");
                    Log.e(TAG, "" + e.getCause().getMessage());

                    if (e.getCause().getMessage() != null && e.getCause().getMessage() != "")
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                e.getCause().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "could not reach server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I handle this problem manually:

1. Download [Volley library from github](https://github.com/google/volley) and add into AndroidStudio project
2. Go to `com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack` class
3. Find `setConnectionParametersForRequest(connection, request);` line inside of `performRequest` method
4. And finally add this codes belew of `setConnectionParametersForRequest(connection, request);` line :

> ```
> // for avoiding this exception : No authentication challenges found
>         try {
>             connection.getResponseCode();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```