# Android Volley get json Object from error responses ( !=200)

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a bit nonstandard situation where server sends in case of error responses (500, 404, ..) also json Object inside of response. But I have a problem to get it in Volley. Is there any way how to parse it from headers ?

Comment: @maxxxo check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/26015610/1168654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. HTTP error codes should not have data in the returned response
2. you can as suggested before, extend Volley's `Request` and override the `parseNetworkResponse` and pass on the data if needed or do anything that is reqired. 

   p.s. remember that it runs off the UI thread but is blocking a network thread, so you can do heavy parsing but should probably only figure out if this is a success or error and let the rest of the chain take care of parsing.
3. You can also write your own `ErrorListener` and figure out what to do upon the different types of errors reponses

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to override `parseNetworkResponse` in `makeStringReq()`