# Prase 401 volley error message

Tags: android, android-volley

How to parse 401 response data for volley,here is the server response am getting i haev used volley network response but its not able to get response data which is in JSON format

```
Status 200 OK 
{
    alert: {
        title: "Unauthorised access to appointment"
        message: ""
    }-
    response: "0"
}



new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Req Failed!");
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        NetworkResponse localNetworkResponse = error.networkResponse;
        if (localNetworkResponse != null) {
            if (!WebAPIEngine.checkStatusCodeVolley(localNetworkResponse.statusCode)) {
                AlertDialogUtil.displayErrorAlert(error.toString(), mContext);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(error.getMessage());
                    if (WebAPIEngine.processErrorAlertResp(jsonObject)) {
                        AlertDialogUtil.displayErrorAlert(WebAPIEngine.getErrorMessage(), mContext);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialogUtil.displayErrorAlert(error.toString(), mContext);
                    }
                } 
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried parsing `JSONObject object = new JSONObject(new String(error.networkResponse.data));`?

Comment: error.networkResponse am getting null

Comment: check first if the `error` is an instance of `NoConnectionError` or any other error type which does not contain a networkResponse. In the other case, networkResponse should be set and also should contain the expected data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get response

```
String responseString="";
if (networkResponse != null) {
    try {
        Log.v(TAG , ".getResponseError code :"+networkResponse.statusCode);
        responseString = new String(networkResponse.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(networkResponse.headers));
        Log.v(TAG, ".getResponseError body :" + responseString);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, beware 401 errors are unreliable to handle in Volley: [The SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23163279/1396264) explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

## **UPDATE July 2016**

As [vedant1811](/questions/tagged/vedant1811) mentioned, **401 errors are unreliable to handle in Volley** but I recently found a workaround not mentioned in [The S.O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948006/http-status-code-in-android-volley-when-error-networkresponse-is-null/23163279#23163279) and I thought it could be useful if the provided solutions does not suit your case.

1) Create a base request extending any volley request (StringRequest, JSONObjectRequest, etc...) and override ***parseNetworkError()*** function

```
/* Custom volley request. I chose to extend JsonObjectRequest
 * feel free to extend any other volley class
 */ 
public class CundinasRequest extends JsonObjectRequest{
...
  @Override
  //This will make the volley error message to contain your server's error message
  protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
      if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
          volleyError = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
      }
      return volleyError;
  }
...
}
```

2) In your ***onErrorResponse()*** implementation you just have to parse your server's error. Here's an example:

```
//Volley request is made somewhere in this activity
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private final String AUTH_ERROR_IDENTIFIER = "invalid_token";
...
  public isAuthorizationError(VolleyError error){
    return error.getMessage().contains(AUTH_ERROR_IDENTIFIER); 
  }

  @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      if(isAuthorizationError(error)
        Log.e(TAG, "Please log in again");
  }

}
```

I found this workaround useful as I couldn't change the server's return status and the authorization error was always the same. To give you an idea, it looked something like this:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Invalid access token: AN INVALID TOKEN"
}
```