# Change status code Rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, android-volley, http-status-code-401

I am in a really bad situation.

I am using Volley on an Android application with Ruby on Rails JSON API.

Problem is there is a bug with Volley making it unable to correctly identify anything with staus 401. Basically, whenever there is a 401 status, the NetworkResponse is null and VolleyError is of type NoConnectionError.

I have searched a lot and the only way around it is to return 403 instead of 401 which can be identified correctly by Volley.

How can I change status codes on all responses to 403 if they are 401 in rails? I can't control all the actions and return 403 for example in devise premade actions.

Is there a way to finalize responses or something in rails?

Comment: If you cannot control rails API status codes, try alternative solutions like  extending the Request<T> and overriding parseNetworkResponse as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948006/http-status-code-in-android-volley-when-error-networkresponse-is-null

Comment: I did that but when the response returns 401 the NetworkResponse is null.

Comment: You can add volley as a module and modify BasicNetwork.java to return correct response

Comment: @random Mind telling me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem from the `Ruby on Rails` backend side that is generalized for the whole application which is required as a lot of controllers would also give `401` and not only `devise`.

I have used `Rack` middleware by doing the following:

`app/middleware/unauthorized_to_forbidden.rb`

```
class   UnauthorizedToForbidden
    def initialize(app)
        @app = app 
    end

    def call(env)
        status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
        if(status == 401)
            status = 403
        end
        [status, headers, response]
    end
end
```

`config/application.rb`

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use "UnauthorizedToForbidden"
end
```

Now `UnauthorizedToForbidden` is at the bottom of the `Rack` stack and gets executed at the very end before the response is actually sent to the user. It basically changes the status code if it's `401` to `403`.

Answer (score 1):

Since devise is using warden you can create a custom failureapp and set the http status which you want.

In lib/custom_failure.rb

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    self.status = 403 
    self.content_type = 'json'
    self.response_body = { error: "Invalid Email or password."}.to_json
  end 
end
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

In config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Comment: I will try that but does this become the failure response for anything else that is inside devise?

Answer (score 1):

401 status code might come with a blank response data and if you check this [volley code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java) line 63-75

```
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
```

if jsonString is blank it still tries to create a JSONObject from it `new JSONObject(jsonString)` which throws a JSONException

You may download volley source code, import it as module in your android studio project, add it dependency and make this correction:

```
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
//          Fix for an error on blank success response
//          return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
//                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            if (!jsonString.trim().contentEquals("")) {
                return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
            else {
                return Response.success(new JSONObject(),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

**To add [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to your project - clone the Volley repository and set it as a library project**

1. Git clone the repository by typing the following at the command line:

   `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley`
2. Import the downloaded source into your app project as an Android library module as described in [Create an Android Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html).

You may also try [Prase 401 volley error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927047/prase-401-volley-error-message) if you don't want a fix inside the imported library: