# How to parameter response 422 with gem stripe_event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

I use gem stripe_event with stripe webhook.

My initial code is:

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'checkout.session.completed', StripeCheckoutSessionService.new
end
```

app/services/stripe_checkout_session_service.rb

```
class StripeCheckoutSessionService
  def call(event)
    order = Order.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
    order.update(state: "paid")
  end
end
```

My problem is that if order is nil, I have a 500 error, and I want to have a 422 error instead.

I try that :

app/services/stripe_checkout_session_service.rb

```
class StripeCheckoutSessionService
  def call(event)
    order = Order.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
    if order
      order.update(state: "paid")
      head :accepted
    else
      head :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

head is not recognize by the service, I try to return a string instead and return head directly in the block but I'm locked now...

Does anybody have any idea for me ?

Comment: When you say you want a different error code, do you mean you want your code to raise a 422 when it catches a 500? If so, something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38851247/100328) would work.

Comment: For now, if my code doesn't find order, I have a 500, but I want to improve my code to answer with a 422, which is more logic than a 500

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a string, probably you can do this:

```
class StripeCheckoutSessionService
  def call(event)
    order = Order.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
    if order
      order.update(state: "paid")
      "Successfully updated!" # or do this { status: 400, msg: 'success' }
    else
      "Error occurred!" # or do this { status: 422, msg: 'unprocessable_entity' }
    end
  end
end
```

Haven't tried this but should work.

Comment: This return a string when call the service, but what I want is to answer head :422 to the webhook