# HttpStatus become deprecated in API level 22

Tags: android, http, rest-client

Usually I used to check for the server different code responses in my `RestClient` class using the `org.apache.http.HttpStatus` class as the following example:

```
if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == restClient.getResponseCode()) {
            //200 OK (HTTP/1.0 - RFC 1945)
            return true;
} else if (HttpStatus.SC_BAD_GATEWAY == restClient.getResponseCode()){
           //502 Bad Gateway (HTTP/1.0 - RFC 1945)
            return false;
}
```

But recently the class became **deprecated since API level 22** according to the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html)

> This interface was deprecated in API level
>   22. Please use [openConnection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) instead. Please visit this [webpage](http://android-developers.blogspot.ae/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for further details.

But using `OpenConnection()` method for me does not make any sense.

**My Question is:** Is there any other way to do the same functionality without needing to hardcode all the code responses by myself within the application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since HttpClient is deprecated, please, use other clients for http communication. I see no issue with having status codes defined in your code.

Comment: @IgorFilippov listing all the possible `CodeResponses` is reinventing the wheel . Check out the accepted answer to understand what I mean

Answer (score 95, accepted):

you can cast the returned value of `openConnection` to `HttpURLConnection`, and use `getResponseCode()` to retrieve response code

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
final int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

} else if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY) {

}
```

`HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode())

Comment: `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot