# Android Volley with compileSdk = 24

Tags: android-studio, httprequest, android-volley

I was all excited to use Android volley to make http requests to an api, but then found it uses `org.apache.http.HttpStatus`, which was deprecated in compileSdk 24.  any newer versions?  I think it's causing all sorts of compiler problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941328/httpstatus-become-deprecated-in-api-level-22

Comment: true, this addresses the underlying issue of HttpStatus's deprecation, but it doesn't address the fact that the library would have to be re-written around that new platform.  I could try to re-write the whole Volley library using the updated import, but your link doesn't really address my question; I'm asking about Volley.