# How can I get a JSON status that my server is busy?

Tags: java, android, json

My JSON Code:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            int success = jsonResponse.getInt("success");

                            if (success == 0) {

                            }
                            if (success == 1) { 

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                nRequest nRequest = new nRequest(edtTextReg.getText().toString(), responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(login.this);
                queue.add(nRequest);
```

How can I find a way that JSON give me the status "server is busy"? Busy means for example: thousands of people use my server.

Comment: That definition of busy is basically useless. How does your code know how many people are using the server?

Comment: This is my question. How can I find a way that JSON give me the status "server is busy"

Comment: Why do you need the status? What are your criteria?

Comment: I need this for a login request. The user need a Toast, that the Server is busy

Comment: If your server's really slammed you may need to do this at the HTTP server level and have a JSON "error document" configured.

Answer (score 2):

Http status code for server overload is 503.

**503 - Service Unavailable**
*A 503 status code is most often seen on extremely busy servers, and it indicates that the server was unable to complete the request due to a server overload.*

> so your code should be something like this:

```
                @Override

                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                 int status = jsonResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                      int success = jsonResponse.getInt("success");
                        if (status == 503) {
                          // 
                        }

                        if (success == 0) {

                        }
                        if (success == 1) { 

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: I get an error: "Cannot resolve Method 'getStatusLine()'"

Comment: For getting the status code correctly you could refer to this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948006/http-status-code-in-android-volley-when-error-networkresponse-is-null

Answer (score 0):

If your server is busy you don't want it to spend time rendering a JSON, moreover, if server load is in your mind you might end up putting your application behind a load-balancer and those usually knows nothing about JSON.

The proper way to handle this situation is to parse the correct HTTP status code, usually 429, see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/233519/what-is-the-proper-http-status-for-too-many-connections)

To access the status code your onResponse should look like this:

```
@Override    
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, String content) {
}
```