# Android 4.1.2 connection.getResponseCode() returns IOException wrongly

Tags: android, android-volley, http-status-code-401, challenge-response

I'm using Volley in my app to make HTTP calls to my rest server.
When a user is not authenticated (no SESSION ID cookie) the server returns a 401.

But with Android 4.1.2 (with Android higher that 4.2.2 I don't have this problem) the calls fails with this error

```
java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
```

I had a look around and apparently it's because my server doesn't return the WWW-Authenticate header. But even after I made the change server side, I still get the same error when the app tries to make a call without valid cookie.

I have debugged a bit a in the HUrlStack when the code attempt a

```
connection.getResponseCode();
```

it returns that IOException error. But if a Re-do that call (with the Debugger) it then returns the correct 401... !

Could someone explain what's happening? Is this possible to fix only server side?

Comment: This is a known issue in Android. Check this response:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15973063