# HttpUrlConnection with post request and parameter as JSON object?

Tags: java, android, json

The same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976240/httpurlconnection-with-post-request-and-parameter-as-json-object-android) but I want to make a request with following structure.

```
"method": "post",

"url": parserApiUrl,

"data": {

"url": s3BaseUrl + imageKey

},

"headers": {

"x-api-key": "sdsdasdwdw"

}
```

Comment: Please have a look on how to make a network request. 
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: on that tutorial he used to get result as json, here i want to send "data:{file:value}" and "headers:{xapi:value}" to server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Found a solution for this by this steps

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-api-key", x_api);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                String datajson =  "{\"file\": \""+imageString.trim()+"\"}";
                Log.e("data","json:"+datajson);

                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(datajson.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                os.close();
```