# HTTP Basic Authentication With URLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, basic-authentication

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(mURL).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
String basicAuth = params[0] + ":" + params[1];
basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(basicAuth.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth);
connection.connect();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
```

I have gone through all possible questions based on this on SO but with out any success. I am trying to connect to my server using basic authentication. But when I try to access the input stream from `URLConnection` it throws `IOException`. Thanks for any help from any one of you.

Comment: Do you have the internet permission declared in your manifest?

Comment: Those every thing is set I do have other HTTP request happening parallel in my application

Comment: Throws *what* `IOException.` With what message? stack trace?

Comment: File not found exception. And Thanks for all of your time I was bit late to  respond. I fixed the issue connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth); instead of this I added connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth);   now it working fine now. But I do like to know what effect this will make over the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, here there could be a few things that can go wrong. 
Does the URL you are trying to connect to exist? If not, may be you may have to redirect.
Also, try

```
connection.getResponseCode();
```

and make sure it returns 200 or HTTP_OK

Needs more information to say anything. Go to debug mode and try to get the states of different objects used here.

Similar to [IOException: "Received authentication challenge is null" (Apache Harmony/Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357372/ioexception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null-apache-harmony-android?rq=1)