# Retrofit error java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit

I try to send on post a id application this work with HttpPost but when I try to do this with Retrofit I have the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
```

Here is the method to post application id:

```
  @POST("/acces_token")
  @Headers({ "Content-type: application/json" })
  Response identifierApplication(@Header("X-FTVEN-ID") String header);
```

I searched on google but I didn't find this error with retrofit.

Thank's for your response

Answer (score 0):

Try adding also:

```
@Headers({ "WWW-Authenticate: None"})
```

As per this question: [IOException: "Received authentication challenge is null" (Apache Harmony/Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357372/ioexception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null-apache-harmony-android)