# JSoup throws "Received authentication challenge is null" Exception only in android 2.x

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I wrote a code to parse and manipulate some data in a 3rd party website using jsoup.
The website reponses HTTP 401 if user is not logged in and shows login form. Since JSoup throws exceptions in these cases(Http response is not 2xx or 3xx) i used `ignoreHttpErrors(true)` in my connection.

The odd part is when i test the android application that uses that code it works fine on android ICS, Kitkat and lollipop but when i test it in android 2.3.7 on emulator the following code throws IOException with "Received authentication challenge is null" message.

```
       Jsoup.connect(address)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
            .timeout(30 * 1000)
            .execute()
```

and the as i mentioned `ignoreHttpErrors` doesn't help. What is different between these versions?! (I am trying to run it on android 3.x too) Is this something about JSoup or android? Is there a workaround to have compatibility with android 2.x?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931791/java-io-ioexception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null-in-ics-4-0-3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357372/ioexception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null-apache-harmony-android. Maybe the versions of android that work as expected are treating the malformed response differently.

Comment: @alkis I'm using jsoup, not directly using HttpConnection class

Comment: I believe you meant `HttpURLConnection` class. Jsoup uses `HttpURLConnection` underneath, and as it seems, when it receives this error, since it's not an Http error, it bubbles it so you can catch it. What I'm trying to say, is that there is no difference. What you can do to have it work, is to catch it, and treat it as you like.